# Multimerch seller add and edit error

Tags: php, json, opencart2.x

I am using Opencart v.2.1.0.1. I have used Multimerch for seller listing and seller profile management. I am getting the error below when I try to add or edit seller profile from admin panel. Please help.

Error code :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>
> OK
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html dir="ltr" lang="en">
> <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
>     <title>Permission Denied!</title>
>     <base href="https://localhost/shoppercrux/admin/" />
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
>     <link href="view/stylesheet/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
>     <link href="view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
>     <link href="view/javascript/summernote/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/summernote/summernote.js"></script>
>     <script src="view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
>     <script src="view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
>     <link href="view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
>     <link type="text/css" href="view/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
>     <script src="view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; var msGlobals = { config_limit_admin: '20', config_language: 'view/javascript/multimerch/datatables/lang/en.lng' }; </script>          
> </head>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're using the latest version of MultiMerch for OpenCart 2.1.x (7.7.5.1).

If you're using older versions upload the vqmod/xml/multimerch_oc21x_controllerfix.xml from the MultiMerch archive to your store. That will fix it.